# Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:59113

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

I get this error when I want to add a user to Selenium options

code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=/home/ali/.config/google-chrome/Default")
```

error:

```
File "/home/ali/programming/something/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    driver = UC.Chrome(executable_path=driverLocation, options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 401, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 589, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 370, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:44063
from chrome not reachable
```

system:

> chrome 103.0.5060.134
> ubuntu 22.04

**It works correctly when I don't add a user**
how can i fix it ??(When I want to add a user)

Thanks

Comment: Update your chrome